# how to remove html class from magento2

Tags: magento2, layout, template, theme

This is default class `header content` and `footer content`

```
<header class="page-header">
     <div class="header content">
```

**how to remove them?** I cannot find any way to do that and also don't want to use js quick fix for that. any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I reckon you should be able to do:

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" htmlClass="">
```

As well as

```
<referenceContainer name="footer" htmlClass="">
```

In your layout.

Comment: @QaisarSatti you're welcome ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems not to work anymore in Magento 2.2+

Comment: That DO not work in magento 2.2 because of XSD...

Comment: it is work in M2.3.3